# Unity asking to enter Safe Mode?

Tags: unity

I installed 2021.3.2f1 with the documentation and WebGL module and created a new project from Unity Hub. When I try opening that though I get this:
[image: error]

Not sure why this is happening. I deleted the old installation from both Unity Hub and Finder on my Mac. I actually had installation issues with 2021.3.2f1 before it got installed successfully so I deleted and reinstalled both Unity and Unity Hub.

If I click ignore and open the project, I get a pretty long "DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path" error -- and apparently I can't add scripts to any object because of this error:
"DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/Applications/2021.3.2f1/Unity.app/Contents/UnityReferenceAssemblies/unity-4.8-api/Facades'."

Plus, I noticed that in this project's folder, the "Assembly-CSharp.csproj" file is not there. I see the file in all my other projects which were done in the previous editor version (2020.3.30f1).

What does the safe mode and directory error mean though? Did I do anything that caused this? What should I do? I'm on Mac btw. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: [We have some past Q&A about similar exceptions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunity%5D+DirectoryNotFoundException), which might have some leads for you. StackOverflow is also a good place to search for exception details.

Comment: You mention you had install issues before reinstalling, and the the error message seems to indicate that files are missing from your installation, so maybe even though it seemed like it installed correctly the second time, it actually still isn't installed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to make a new project open it in unity. Close unity and copy the asset folder over to the new project and then reopen unity and let it process each asset again. Then resetup your project settings. It’s a pain but I’ve found it the cleanest way to move between major versions.